# How to pass the values from one jsp page to another jsp without submit button?

Tags: jsp

This is my demo1.jsp page,

```
<body>
    <form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="demo2.jsp">-->
    <input type="text"  name="usnername" />
    <input type="text" name="password"/>        
    <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="window.location.href='demo2.jsp'" />
</form>
```

This is my demo2.jsp

```
<body>
    <%
    String Uname=request.getParameter("usnername");
    String Usecret=request.getParameter("password");
    out.println(Uname);
    out.println(Usecret);
    %>
```

Here this code is working fine but ,How can i get values from demo1 to demo2 without using sumbit button?i.e., `<input type="submit" value="go" onclick="window.location.href='demo2.jsp'" />` bt using input type="button" can we send values.

Comment: question is not understandable can elaborate more on "without sumbit button" ?

Comment: On which event then you want to submit form?

Comment: then how you wanna navigate to demo2.jsp?

Comment: Why not using a submit button? Don't ever use GET to send a password. Use a form, using POST as method, and do use a submit button. And learn to use servlets, and to avoid scriptlets in your JSPs.

Comment: <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="window.location.href='demo2.jsp'" /> rather than submit button can we pass values by putting <iput type="button" .....>

Comment: Its working when i write input type= button inside <form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="demo2.jsp">
</form> but i dont want to use submit button other way i need,please help me.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a submit button to submit a form? That's what they're for.

Comment: is there any other way to get values in demo2.jsp without using form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to include following script.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
        var xmlHttp  
        function showState(str)
        {
            //if you want any text box value you can get it like below line. 
            //just make sure you have specified its "id" attribute
            var name=document.getElementById("id_attr").value;
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
            {
              xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            var url="forwardPage.jsp";
            url +="?count1=" +str+"&count2="+name";
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        function stateChange()
        {   
            if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
            {   
                document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
            }   
        }
      </script>
```

So if you got the code, let me tell you, div_id will be id of div tag where you have to show your result.
By using this code, you are passing parameters to another page. Whatever the processing is done there will be reflected in div tag whose id is "div_id".
You can call showState(this.value) on "onChange" event of any control or "onClick" event of button not submit.
Further queries will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to Understand your Question and it seems that you want the values in the first JSP to be available in the Second JSP.

1. It is very bad Habit to Place Java Code snippets Inside JSP file, so that code snippet should go to a servlet.
2. Pick the values in a servlet ie.

   ```
   String username = request.getParameter("username");
   String password = request.getParameter("password");
   ```
3. Then Store the Values inside the Session:

   ```
   HttpSession sess = request.getSession(); 
   sess.setAttribute("username", username);
   sess.setAttribute("password", password);
   ```
4. These values Will be available anywhere in the Application as long as the session is valid.

   ```
   HttpSession sess = request.getSession(false); //use false to use the existing session
   sess.getAttribute("username");//this will return username anytime in the session
   sess.getAttribute("password");//this will return password Any time in the session
   ```

I hope this is what you wanted to know, but please do not use code snippets in the JSP. You can always get the values into the JSP using `jstl` in the JSPs:

```
 ${username}//this will give you the username in the JSP
 ${password}// this will give you the password in the JSP
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: Give accurate path details for Form1.jsp in Test.jsp
1. Test.jsp and 2.Form1.jsp

Test.jsp

```
<body>
<form method ="get" onsubmit="Form1.jsp">
<input type="text" name="uname">
<input type="submit" value="go" ><br/>
</form>
</body>
```

Form1.jsp

```
</head>
<body>
<% String name=request.getParameter("uname"); out.print("welcome "+name); %>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in either of this ways , triggering an `onclick` on a form button like this,

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="demo2.jsp">
    <input type="text"  name="usnername" />
    <input type="text" name="password"/>        
    <input type="button" value="go" onclick="submitForm" />
</form>
```

And using `javascript`,

```
        function submitForm() {                
            document.forms[0].submit();
            return true;
        }
```

or you could also try `Ajax` to post your page

here is the link [jQueryAjax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

And also nice startup examples [using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax) and [here](http://www.programming-free.com/2013/03/ajax-fetch-data-from-database-in-jsp.html)

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly know what you want to do.But you cant send data of one form using a submit button of another form.

You could do one thing either use sessions or use hidden fields that has the submit button. You could use javascript/jquery to pass the values from the first form to the hidden fields of the second form.Then you could submit the form.

Or else the easiest you could do is use sessions.

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[firstname]" id="elm_6">
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[lastname]" id="elm_7">
</form>

<form action="#">
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[b_firstname]" id="elm_14">
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[s_firstname]" id="elm_16">

<input type="submit" value="Continue" name="dispatch[checkout.update_steps]">
</form>


$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
$('#elm_14').val($('#elm_6').val());
$('#elm_16').val($('#elm_7').val());
});
```

This is the jsfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/FPsdy/102/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also,

Html:

```
<form action="javascript:next()" method="post">
<input type="submit" value=Submit /></form>
```

Javascript:

```
      function next(){
        //Location where you want to forward your values
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:8563/And/try1.jsp?dymanicValue=" + values; 
        }
```