# How can I prevent the shopping cart item from incrementing when the user refresh the page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I made a shopping cart using servlet and jsp but i'm facing a problem which increments the quantity of cart item whenever I refresh the `cart` page. Actually what i'm doing is passing the particular `product ID` in the url whenever user click the add to cart button on some product just like `addtocart.jsp?id=3` and then in according to the id I extract the product from the database and add it in the cart but when I refresh this URL **addtocart?id=3** the whole procedure in this page run again which increments the product quantity everytime of a refresh. 
How can I solve this problem. Any suggestions?

`product.jsp`

```
<%
 String id = request.getParameter("id");
 Connection con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select * from products inner join images using(product_name) "
         + "where product_id=?");
 ps.setString(1,id);
 ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
 rs.next();

 String name = rs.getString("product_name");
 String image = rs.getString("image_name");
 String company = rs.getString("company_name");
 String category =  rs.getString("category_name");
 String sub = rs.getString("sub_category_name");
 double price = rs.getDouble("price");
 String summary = rs.getString("summary");
 int hits = rs.getInt("hits");

 //out.println(price);
%>
   <div class="container_16" style="background: #FFF;">
       <div class="grid_16 productHeading">
           <h2 class="heading"><%=name %>- By <%= company %> <%=category%> </h2>
       </div>

       <div class="grid_10">

             <h5>Category: <a href="#" onclick="return false"><%= category %> </a> >
              <a href="#" onclick="return false">  <%= sub %> </a><br/><br/>
              Priced At <span class="Bigred">RS. <%=price %></span> 
             </h5>

             <h2>Summary Of this Item</h2>


                       <div class="grid_5" id="addtocart">
                           <a href="addToCart.jsp?id=<%=id%>">
                              Add To Cart
                           </a>
                           <% if(session.getAttribute("admin")!=null)
                              {
                           %>   
                              <a href="addToCart.jsp?id=<%=id%>">
                              Edit  
                           </a>
                          <%              
                            }
                           %>   
                       </div>

               <br/>

             <h6 class="grey">Summary of <%= name%></h6>
                    <p class="info">
                        <%= summary%>
                    </p>       

       </div>  

       <div class="grid_4" id="pimage">
           <img src="<%= image%>">
       </div>    

  </div>
```

Comment: Is your form method GET or POST?

Comment: Its a GET request.

Comment: So make it a POST request.

Comment: Search the cart to see if the submitted ID already exists, then do nothing?

Answer (score 2):

Use *Post/Redirect/Get* Pattern:

1. Submit form with POST method instead of GET
2. Redirect back to cart page after processing post request.

[image: Post/Redirect/Get flow]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possibilities to prevent this from happening.

1. Change the form method to POST so that the browser asks the user if they want to resubmit the form if they ever refresh
2. Redirect the form after it is accepted

Have a look at the answers to this question [How to avoid resubmit in jsp when refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317486/how-to-avoid-resubmit-in-jsp-when-refresh)

After looking at your edited code, I would suggest adding code to remove the session variable after it is processed OR just use a hidden form and pass the parameters using the input tags

Comment: but I'm not using a form it is just a simple link to the addtocart.jsp

Comment: can I do it without using the form and hidden parameter?

Comment: Let me get this straight, every time a customer adds something to the cart, they are redirected to a new page?

Comment: yes they are redirected to the addtocart.jsp with an id

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Anyway, look at my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

look at your code

```
  <a href="addToCart.jsp?id=<%=id%>">
```

use

```
        var url="addtocart.jsp";
        url +="?id=" +value;
```

and pass url as GET method

or

```
<a href="addToCart.jsp?id="<%=id%>>
```

not resolve then follow

[How to pass the values from one jsp page to another jsp without submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286619/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-jsp-page-to-another-jsp-without-submit-button)