# Accessing iframe from one page to another page of jsp in javascript function

Tags: javascript

My Form1.jsp has iframe

```
<iframe id="results" name="results" style="display: none;"  
width="100%" height="240" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```

I want to access iframe id in javascript function in My form2.jsp

```
function Hide() {
  if(document.getElementById("results").style.display=="none")  {
    document.getElementById("results").style.display="block";
  }
}
```

in the place results string I want to access iframe id from Form1.jsp

Comment: And what is the result? Any console errors? Where is form2? In the iFrame? Can you post more HTML? Also you call the function hide but it should show. Also you may want to set the style by script so the test works - try `console.log(document.getElementById("results").style.display)` to see it is likely not "none" when you expect it to be - read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866229/can-you-check-an-objects-css-display-with-javascript

Comment: the javascript function Hide() in form2.jsp i want to access the iframe id in form1.jsp throught javascript Hide() in form2.jsp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286619/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-jsp-page-to-another-jsp-without-submit-button

Comment: Please show the HTML with both forms

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. redirect from Myform1.jsp to Myform2.jsp using jsp redirect method

> public void response.sendRedirect("Myform2.jsp/?formid=id") throws IOException

add it in form1.jsp.

id = your id, you want to send.

2. In form2.jsp, Read the Url and get the query.

Comment: where we need to add public void response.sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException method. Is it in Form1.jsp or Form2.jsp

Comment: by using above method we are able to access entire jsp page but i want to access only iframeid from one jsp to another jsp page

Comment: Ok, Then attach the iframe id with your url , then get it back in the second page using ajax.

Comment: Are you using Rest API.

Comment: You didn't add enough line of codes in you question. However I will try my best to explain.

Comment: How the javascript function redirect to form2.jsp.May i need to call the function on any button event

Comment: Here you are accessing the form id but i want to access the iframe id. can i use same method for iframe id.